# Es posible hacer un array de varias clases en Java

Tags: java

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto personal en donde el usuario escribe en un campo de texto y luego darle a un boton para procesar lo que puso y quiero que primero lo mande a otra clase hay verifica primero si lo que ingreso esta en un HashMap, si devuelve null para a un bucle for para comprobar si lo que puso esta en otra clase

ej:

```
public void primclass(String datodelusuario){ 

  //Todo el codigo para crear y tomar el dato de un HashMap
  if(//entrara si el HashMap devuelve null){



   for(//recorrera todo el array de las clases que quiero poner para ver hasta que una no devuelva null){


     //codigo
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. He intentado editarla, pero es imposible entender lo que quieres: "y quiero que primero lo mande a otra clase hay verifica primero..." o "si devuelve null para a un bucle for para comprobar si lo que puso esta en otra clase". Esto es incomprensible. Por favor, reescribe tu pregunta para que podamos entenderte y ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Podriaa poner un ejemplo? No está claro el problema. Lo que entiendo es que el usuario escribe algo y quieres ver si lo que escribió está en alguna clase. ¿Estas clases tienen una propiedad  en particular o es algo como un buscador de clases?

Comment: Otra consulta, ¿el arreglo contiene  _clases_ o _objetos_?

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
List lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Dentro de esa lista puedes guardar objetos de diferentes tipos.

Y para recorrer la lista haces algo como esto:

```
for(Object o : lista){
   if(o instanceof ClaseA){}
   else if(o instanceof ClaseB){}
}
```

Otra solución posible sería esta:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     List lista = new ArrayList<Valor>();

     lista.add(new A());
     lista.add(new B());

    for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size(); i++){
        if(((Valor)lista.get(i)).getValor()){
            // el valor esta en este objeto
        }
    }


    }

}
  interface Valor{
     public boolean getValor(String datoUsuario);
 }
 class A implements Valor{
     @Override public boolean getValor(String datoUsuario){
         //buscar dentro de clase el valor y retornar true si existe en clase A
         return true;
     }
 }
 class B implements Valor{
      @Override public boolean getValor(String datoUsuario){
         //buscar dentro de clase el valor y retornar true si existe en clase B
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Haces que tus objetos implementen una interfaz que te servirá para saber si ese objeto del array contiene el valor que deseas.

Comment: Si podria servir pero yo lo que en realidad necesito crear la lista o el array con todas las clases y luego usar una dos funciones que tiene esa clase una para enviarle los datos y otra para que me los retorne, si retorna null que pruebe con otra clase que este en el array hasta que una clase no retorne null String n = null; int x = 0; List clases = new ArrayList<Object>(); //añadir las clases a la lista while(n == null){ //tomar lo que hay en la lista con la posición x y llamar a una de sus funciones //llamar a otras de las funciones de la clase que esta en la posición x para que n sea al str